# Regular expression to extract the string starting from a certain character without that character itself

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have the following js code:

```
r='d|daa|dd';  
reg = /\|.*/;  
result = reg.exec(r);
```

This will return `|daa|dd`, but what I want is `daa|dd`.

What should the regex be? Thanks

Comment: It's a shame js doesn't support lookbehind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r='d|daa|dd';
reg = /\|(.*)/;
result = reg.exec(r);
```

`result[1]` is then populated with what's in the capture group.

Comment: Ah thanks. But is it possible to directly return a string instead of an array?

Comment: @NSF: Simply return `result[1]`. It's the best way to go, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping is the way to go:

```
reg = /\|(.*)/;
```

It will search for string starting with |, but will capture the group (enclosed in brackets) separately for further use.